# How to get the list of "effective" Git ignore patterns?

Tags: git

It is possible in a Git repo to have multiple "ignore files" in effect at the same time. Is there a way to get a list of the effective ignore *patterns*, merging from all currently active `.gitignore` files?

Note that I am specifically asking for the list of *patterns*, not the names of ignored files themselves.

Comment: `git check-ignore -v <files>` will tell you which line of which .gitignore is ignoring the files, but I don't know of one which merges them all together.

Comment: @Schwern that also unfortunately doesn't show me the effective *patterns*, just whether some specific files are ignored.

Comment: It will show the pattern which ignored the file with -v. It's not a complete answer, but might help solve whatever problem you're solving. BTW what problem are you solving?

Comment: @Schwern I wanted to use the full effective set of ignore patterns in order to write a command line tool that would mimic Git's own ignores as closely as possible (specifically, passing the ignored patterns to `tree` which supports glob-like ignore patterns with its `-I` option). Maybe instead I need to generate the output, then loop over it removing elements for which `git check-ignore` exits with 0.

Comment: Would `git ls-files` do the trick?